# Serve mp3 through TCP server

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, tcp, mp3

I'm trying to serve a mp3 file through a TCP server just adding some headers to emulate a HTTP server. The headers that I'm currently using are:

```
var header = `HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\r\nContent-Type: audio/mpeg\r\nContent-Length: ${fileStat.size}\r\n'Cache-Control: no-cache'\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nLast-Modified: ${date.toGMTString()}\r\n\r\n`
```

An the way I create the server:

```
let server =  net.createServer((socket) => {
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
      socket.write(Buffer(header, 'ascii'))
      RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream('/storage/sdcard1/Music/elpisito.mp3', 'ascii')
      .then((stream) => {
        stream.open()
        stream.onData((chunk) => {
          socket.write(Buffer(chunk, 'ascii'))
        })
        stream.onEnd(() => {
          socket.end()
        })
      })
    }
  })
  socket.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error ' + error)
  })
}).listen(serverPort, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('opened server on ' + JSON.stringify(server.address()))
})
```

If I don't send any header (I delete the `socket.write(Buffer(header, 'ascii'))`) I download the file with a sample request that looks like this:

```
http://192.168.0.12:65000/song.mp3
```

The problem is that I want to serve the song as streaming but I don't know how to handle the requests and how to set the proper header.

This is a snapshot of a sample request:
[image]

As you can see in the server code, the response is written with `socket.write` and this is triggered in an `data` event handler where I have access to a data info about the requests. This is a snapshot of the first (there are two) request data:

[image]